# Gated EF migrations for SQL scripts in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, entity-framework-migrations, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have been researching how to gate database updates between environments by using Azure DevOps and I´m finding Azure DevOps to surprisingly lack in this regards, so I´m hoping I´m missing something.

**How would you gate/review a EF Core migration script with Azure DevOps?**

Here is my **"poor mans"** version of it, but there must be another way, right?

---

Create a idempotent migration script in a build step

[image]

Then create a separate release step
[image]

and in that step we out put the migration script to the log window

[image]

and when the release stage is hit, we will need to Resume (approved) the change, but not before you "View logs" so you can view the migration script content.

[image]

that looks like this

[image]

This is just **not** great at all.. So is there another way to do it in Azure DevOps or do I need to start looking at e.g. Octopus Deploy?

p.s
And how could I create a rollback script at build time? Is it possible to get "this" and "last" migration so you could create a rollback.

e.s.
I have asked this question at [EF Core repo](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/3515) and at [VS Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/A-task-for-gated-review-of-EF-Core-Migra/1564076?space=21&q=Gated%20review%20of%20EF%20Core%20Migration%20script%20on%20release%3F%20&entry=myfeedback) and on [Azure Pipelines Task repo](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/15461)

Answer (score 0):

The first question that comes to mind: if this scenario is not great, what *would* be a great scenario?

For per-environment reviews, please have a look at using environments in Azure DevOps.

> An environment is a collection of resources that you can target with deployments from a pipeline. Typical examples of environment names are Dev, Test, QA, Staging, and Production.

More info: [Create and target an environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments).

Combined with Approvals you can ...

> Manually control when a stage should run using approval checks. Use approval checks to control deployments to production environments. Checks are available to the resource Owner to control when a stage in a pipeline consumes a resource. As the owner of a resource, such as an environment, you can define approvals and checks that must be satisfied before a stage consuming that resource starts.

You can use these approvals as a check for your SQL script.

Entity Framework migrations enables you to (have the framework automatically) create `Up()` and `Down()` methods, for migrations and their rollback. For more information, see [Managing Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing).

**EDIT:**
Additionally, you might want to look into [Release gates and approvals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/?view=azure-devops) .

> Teams can also take advantage of the Approvals and Gates feature to control the workflow of the deployment pipeline. Each stage in a release pipeline can be configured with pre-deployment and post-deployment conditions that can include waiting for users to manually approve or reject deployments, and checking with other automated systems that specific conditions are met. In addition, teams can configure manual validations to pause the deployment pipeline and prompt users to carry out manual tasks then resume or reject the deployment.

[image: The release pipeline workflow]

Comment: To answer your question: A great scenario would be a "artifact view" step that ties into review. So if the artifact is not there, fail. If its there show the content and give me resume/reject.  I´m trying out your suggestion but I can´t see anything there that allows me to view an artifact, just validate its there. Do you?